# Prevent RestSharp changing https to http

Tags: c#-4.0, restsharp

I have a very simple piece of code using v130 of RestSharp. The code itself compiles fine and returns values from the server - the problem is they're not the ones I'm after.

Code

```
private void startTest()
{
    string email = "bob2@example.com";
    string password = "password";
    doRestSharpWebRequest(email, password);
}

private void doRestSharpWebRequest(email, password)
{
     var restClient = new RestClient();
     restClient.BaseUrl = "https://mytestserver.com/api";
     restClient.Authenticator = new SimpleAuthenticator("email", email, "password", password);
     var restRequest = new RestRequest("token", Method.GET);
     restRequest.AddHeader("Accepts", "application/json;version=1");
     restRequest.AddHeader("Authorization", "apikey zyzyz");
     restRequest.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;

     IRestResponse<userlogin> response = restClient.Execute<userlogin>(restRequest);
}
```

where userlogin is just a class to deserialize to.

When I run the code, I'm presented with the following error

```
Message = No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://mytestserver.com/api/token?Email=bob%40example.com&password=password'.
```

Two things are apparent, the @ has been changed to %40 which should cause a problem and the http has been changed to https.

Can restsharp be told not to convert from https and http?

Comment: Your title makes no sense. Is https being changed to http, or is http being changed to https? Your description says that http is changed to https, but looking at your code, I'm not so sure.

Comment: Apologies, it's going from https to http